# Generating an Ellipsoid Grid in python

Tags: python, vector, 3d, grid, shapes

I need to do some work with ellipsoids, but i'm not sure how to write the code for this part. I need to generate a grid around the area of an ellipsoids. I then need to take points on the grid and put them into an string or array. The last part is fine, not sure about the first part. I'm just not sure how to create the grid and points. Any tips would be awesome.

Comment: what type of coordinates (cartesian [x, y, z], polar, cylindrical)?  what kind of ellipsoid - all three axes different size / axes oriented randomly or parallel to your coordinate axes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little bit of NumPy to make meshes. I think you want a 2D grid of points `[i,j]` which are distributed in 3D. In that case `np.meshgrid()` and `np.mgrid()` might not be as convenient as they would be if your grid and space were both 2D or both 3D.

In this example, your coordinates are `x[i,j]`, `y[i,j]` and `z[i]` since they are generated as slices in z in this example. The one on the left is the initial sphere and on the right is stretched into an ellipsoid. The python is a little verbose to make it clearer what is happening.

Do you need something different?

You can rotate each of the plots with the cursor by holding and dragging within the plot area (I mean in your matplotlib window of course, not here - at least until Stackexchange gets WebGL).

[image: screen shot of 3d plots]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

twopi = 2.0 * np.pi

z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 22)[1:-1]
r = np.sqrt(1.0 - z**2)[:,None]
theta = np.linspace(0, twopi, 21)[:-1][None,:]
x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)

print x.shape, y.shape, z.shape

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12,6])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1,projection='3d')

for i in range(20):
    ax.plot(x[:,i], y[:,i], z)
    ax.plot(x[:,i], y[:,i], z, 'ok')
for i in range(20):
    ax.plot(x[i,:], y[i,:], z[i])

ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2,projection='3d')

a, b, c = 0.6, 0.3, 1.0

for i in range(20):
    ax.plot(a*x[:,i], b*y[:,i], c*z)
for i in range(20):
    ax.plot(a*x[i,:], b*y[i,:], c*z[i])

ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)
plt.show()
```